# a handle to a non-managed class is not allowed

Tags: c++, mysql, winforms, user-interface, clr

I'm trying to make a connection between c++ windows form and mysql database,
but it show this error to me.

> a handle to a non-managed class is not allowed

```
        #pragma endregion
        private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            std::string^ constring =L "datasource=localhost;port=**;username=root;password=**";
            MySqlConnection^ conDataBase=gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase=gcnew MySqlCommand("",conDataBase);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is the string class from the C++ Standard Library. You cannot use it with `^` (i.e., as a managed class).

Instead, use the .NET String class:

```
System::String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=**;username=root;password=**";
```